# insert new element after previous added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

JavaScript

```
$(".display_box").on('click', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var x = document.getElementById('added-people').innerHTML;
    $("name").insertAfter(x);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="added-people" 
    style="margin-left:1%;
           min-height:15px;
           width:71.7%;
           background:#f2f4f5;
           font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
           font-size: 9px;color: #212121;">
</div>
```

The display box is generated using a while loop. So, when a display box is clicked, its name is fetched and displayed in the 'added-people' div. I want that when a display box is clicked again, the fetched name should display next to the previous one and so on.

Comment: You have a extra pair of brackets at the end of your code: `});`

Comment: You can't reference innerHTML as a DOM object to `insertAfter()`. That expects an object. And, you're combining jQuery with JavaScript here.

Comment: So much mismatched code, where to begin.

Comment: @SetSailMedia: *"You can't reference innerHTML as a DOM object to insertAfter(). That expects an object."* `insertAfter` accepts strings. Look at the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/). The OP's not using it correctly, but it does accept a string.

Comment: Good point! But if innerHTML contains some markup, yes that'd work. If innerHTML contains only some text, it does not pass as `htmlString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".display_box").on('click', function () {
    var name = $(this).data("name") // use .data() to grab data-name
    var x = $("#added-people") // $("#id") same as document.getElementById('id')
    x.append( '<span>' + name + '</span>' );
});
```

Comment: Why did you add a `span`? The OP didn't say they needed it. Also, using `data` is completely unnecessary if you're not using its special features. Nevertheless, +1 for showing how to `append`.

Comment: Using `.data()` is confusing if you don't know about the implications of jQuery's attribute caching mechanism.

Comment: I added `<span>` so it will be easier for OP to manipulate those added elements in the future, rather than as plain text strings. Like to delete after added, `$("#added-people").on( "click", "span", function(){ $(this).remove(); });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function which appends at the end of text which is **var x** in your case